# Can I override DbContext in EF6 to dynamically select different connection strings?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I came in late to a project developed with asp.net mvc, EF6 and SQL Server. The code is a mess and they use linq everywhere to retrieve data. Now they are about to add a second SQL Server for a different country/language. I can't seem to get my head around the `DbContext` / `IDbConnectionFactory` stuff but can I do it the easy way here and override something, somewhere, so I can insert the right connections string depending on a selected culture?

To simplify:

I want to override `DbContext` so when it is created I can insert a connection string depending on a session value (for example) without specifying a connection string in the constructor.

How would I achieve this? Doing it the right way of course..

Thx!

/Mike

Comment: Why don't you just pass the connection string [in to the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)?

Comment: Then I have to check for which one to use everytime. And it is in maaany places...

Answer (score 1):

Your DBContext must have been created as a partial class. Create you second partial class next to it, and add a static constructor method there

```
public static DBContext Create()
```

Implement the logic inside it, and use this constructor everywhere you need context to be created. This will be kind of factory method. You can define your connection strings in config file and simply create context based on connection string name depending on certain conditions.

What you're trying to achieve is, to some extend, a database sharding architecture.
There are multiple resources on the internet you may want to have a look at to get acquainted with db shards...
i.e. http://www.4tecture.ch/blog/sql-azure-federations-with-entity-framework